# Content-Type tag incorrect when uploading file to s3 using the AWS c++ interface

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to S3 using the AWS C++ SDK. The file transfers just fine but the content type is "binary/octet-stream" instead of "text/html". When I look at the file in the S3 console. There is a "x-amz-meta-content-type" metadata record of type "text/html". How can I set the actual content type of the file I want to upload?

```
int main (int, char**)
{
   Aws::SDKOptions options;
   Aws::InitAPI (options);
   client = new Aws::S3::S3Client;

   Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest request;
   request.SetBucket ("mywebsite.notreal.net");
   request.SetKey ("index.html");
   request.SetACL (Aws::S3::Model::ObjectCannedACL::public_read);
   request.SetContentEncoding ("UTF-8");
   request.AddMetadata ("Content-Type", "text/html");

   auto inputData = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::FStream> ("PutObjectInputStream", "index.html", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::ate);
   request.SetContentLength (inputData-> tellg ());
   request.SetBody (inputData);

   auto result = client-> PutObject (request);
   return result.IsSuccess () ? 0 : 1;
}
```

v

Comment: Don't use `AddMetadata`. The `Content-Type` needs to be set in the HTTP headers of the PUT request. There's a `SetContentType` function available, inherited from `Aws::AmazonStreamingWebServiceRequest`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Content-Type` needs to be set as an HTTP header in the actual PUT request.

Looking at the [documentation](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/0.12.9/dd/dd8/class_aws_1_1_amazon_streaming_web_service_request.html#ab3c257c251ecd26b096a0c3be7dfd69f), there's a `SetContentType` method you can use.